# Inconsistency between html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have following four div's:

```
<div id="air-trigger" onclick="getWidgetData('air-trigger'); getWidgetAirChart();"></div>
<div id="soil-trigger" onclick="getWidgetData('soil-trigger'); getWidgetSoilChart();"></div>
<div id="water-trigger" onclick="getWidgetData('water-trigger'); getWidgetWaterChart();"></div>
<div id="storage-trigger" onclick="getWidgetData('storage-trigger'); getWidgetStorageChart();"></div>
```

I am using two functions under onclick event. getWidgetData function is as follows:

```
function getWidgetData(name){

    var curEl = document.getElementById('time-series');
    curEl.className = "active";

       widgetEl = document.getElementById("soil-chart");

       widgetEl4 = document.getElementById("air-chart");

       widgetEl5 = document.getElementById("water-chart");

       widgetEl6 = document.getElementById("storage-chart");

    //  alert(name);
        var el = document.getElementById('soil-chart');
        el.className = "";


        var el4 = document.getElementById('air-chart');
        el4.className = "";


        var el5 = document.getElementById('water-chart');
        el5.className = "";


        var el6 = document.getElementById('storage-chart');
        el6.className = "";

          if(name == 'air-trigger'){
            widgetEl4.innerHTML = document.getElementById('air-chart').outerHTML; 

                el4.className = "show active";
                el.className = "hide";
                el5.className = "hide";
                el6.className = "hide";

              }

          if(name == 'soil-trigger'){
          widgetEl.innerHTML = document.getElementById('soil-chart').outerHTML; 
            el.className = "show active";
            el4.className = "hide";
            el5.className = "hide";
            el6.className = "hide";
          }

          if(name == 'water-trigger') {

                 widgetEl5.innerHTML = document.getElementById('water-chart').outerHTML; 

                        el5.className = "show active";
                        el.className = "hide";
                        el4.className = "hide";
                        el6.className = "hide";
                  }


          if(name == 'storage-trigger'){
                 widgetEl6.innerHTML = document.getElementById('storage-chart').outerHTML; 

                    el6.className = "show active";
                    el.className = "hide";
                    el4.className = "hide";
                    el5.className = "hide";
                  }


    }
```

getWidgetAirChart(), getWidgetSoildChart(), getWidgetWaterChart(), getWIdgetStorageChart() methods are populating data and showing charts under corresponding div's. If I select "water" tab first then all other tabs are not showing any data using onclick event. But, If I use the "water" tab at last everything working fine. I am not getting why this thing is happening. Any help please. Thans in advance.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: If `getWidgetWaterChart()` is part of the broken path, then why not include the code for that function as well?

Comment: This code could be a lot [DRY-er](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself)

Comment: @Lugia: One id was showing not defined. I didn't notice that before. I fixed the problem. Thanks. :-)